# How to show GtkToolItem in the overflow menu of a GtkToolbar?

Tags: haskell, gtk, toolbar, gtk2hs

I am working on a Haskell application using gtk2hs. This application has a toolbar which consists of several GtkToggleToolButton, GtkToolButton and GtkToolItem elements. For being able to resize the applications window, I set the *[ShowArrow](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gtk/0.12.0/doc/html/Graphics-UI-Gtk-MenuComboToolbar-Toolbar.html#v%3atoolbarSetShowArrow)* attribute to *True*, so that elements, that would be outside the window, are listed in an overflow menu.

This works fine for GtkToggleToolButton and GtkToolButton elements, but GtkToolItem elements do not show up in the menu. This would not be such a big problem, but if those elements are not inside the window frame, the menu arrow does not show up only for them. So that you have no indication that the toolbar has actually more elements.

The GtkToolItem contains a GtkTable which contains a label and two GtkToolButton elements. Can I tell GTK that it should display a label in the overflow menu for my GtkToolItem elements?

Thank you in advance!

Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ToolItem has a method **toolItemSetProxyMenuItem** which allows you to specify the menu item that is displayed in the overflow menu:

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gtk/0.11.0/doc/html/Graphics-UI-Gtk-MenuComboToolbar-ToolItem.html#v:toolItemSetProxyMenuItem

Answer (score 1):

GtkToolButton itself is a GtkToolItem (and you can add that table to it)! Then why you are using GtkToolItem directly?

And I think you should use `GtkToolButton.set_stock_id` (or `set_icon_widget`) aditional to `set_label`, instead of createing a table...

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried using a GtkToolButton but then I weren't able to click on the buttons inside the layout table. I could just click on the outer GtkToolButton.

Comment: @toobb hmmm, so I suggest the second way

Comment: I tried it with set_icon_widget. And when I simply added the table as a child element of GtkToolButton, the table did not even show up. But toolItemSetProxyMenuItem works fine. Thanks for your help!